# Sorting values and grepping the best score (highest number)

Tags: python

I have just started learning Python and I need some help, tips or solution if anybody is willing to help.

I have a file that looks like this:

```
    2  C00000002 score:  -48.649 nathvy =  49 nconfs =         3878
    3  C00000001 score:  -44.988 nathvy =  41 nconfs =         1988
    4  C00000002 score:  -42.674 nathvy =  49 nconfs =         6740
    5  C00000002 score:  -42.453 nathvy =  49 nconfs =         4553
    6  C00000002 score:  -41.829 nathvy =  49 nconfs =         7559
    7  C00000002 score:  -41.156 nathvy =  49 nconfs =         2251
    8  C00000002 score:  -39.520 nathvy =  49 nconfs =         3129
    9  C00000004 score:  -38.928 nathvy =  24 nconfs =          150
   10  C00000002 score:  -38.454 nathvy =  49 nconfs =         9473
   11  C00000004 score:  -37.704 nathvy =  24 nconfs =          156
   12  C00000001 score:  -37.558 nathvy =  41 nconfs =           51
```

My second column are some IDs that are not sorted here, some of them are repeating, such as (`C00000001`) for example. All of them have a different number assigned followed by `score:` (number most often starts with `-`).

What I would like to do is:
1) read second column (non sorted IDs) and to always pick the first one that appears. So in case of `C00000001` it would pick the on with `score :   -44.988`.

2) now when I have unique values presented, I would like to sort them based on the number after `score:`, meaning the most negative number to be on the first position while the most positive one to be on the last position.

Comment: Are you using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/)? Or just pure python? With pandas it's much easier!

Comment: Hi Lucas, so far I haven't used pandas but I can install it and this would be perfect start to use it I guess. So yes, I can use pandas :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using simple python. Python list has sort method inbuilt

```
with open("in_file") as handle:
    already_present = set()
    l = []
    for line in handle:
        line_parts = line.strip().split()
        l.append(line_parts)
        key = line_parts[1]
        if key in already_present:
            continue
        already_present.add(key)

l.sort(key=lambda x:float(x[3]))
```

Comment: Hey, when I modify the name of in_file to the name of my file and run the script it doesn't give me neither error neither output. Have you tried to run this?

Comment: It won't print. The result will be present in list itself. If you do print (l), it'll print the result as you wanted.

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept the answer if it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is a possible solution

```
    def readLine(line,acc):
      result =line.split()
      id=result[1]
      value=result[3]
      if id not in acc:
            acc[id]=value;

    def main():
      filepath = 'myfile.csv'
      acc={};
      with open(filepath) as fp:
            for line in fp:
            readLine(line,acc)
      for key, value in sorted(acc.iteritems(), key=lambda (k, v): (v, k)):
            print "%s: %s" % (key, value)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is *a* possibility:

```
import pprint

scores = {}
for line in open('/tmp/data.txt'):
    _, code, _, score, _, _, _, _, _, _ = line.split()
    if code not in scores:
        scores[code] = score

pprint.pprint(scores)

sorted_by_score = sorted(
    [(code, score) for code, score in scores.items()],
    key=lambda v: v[1],
    reverse=True)

pprint.pprint(sorted_by_score)
```

A list of tuples could be used for the first part, but it'd be slower.